# DNS solution for someuser.com -> domain.com/some-user

Tags: redirect, nginx, web, dns

Let's suppose there is a webpage where someone can create his own profile page.

His profile page is then available at

```
domain.com/some-user
```

Then, this user with profile domain.com/some-user, own his own domain

```
someuser.com
```

and he wants redirect from someuser.com -> domain.com/some-user

How can this be achieved?

I mean what DNS records must be set for someuser.com, and what web-server settings must be set on domain.com

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to redirect him to domain.com host, and via apache, redirect him to domain.com/some-user.

You can do it in several technologies as Java, Php, Ruby, Node, since it's a http header field (host), which you can read and do the processing that you want.

For instance, using apache configured to answer for someuser.com and .htaccess files it would be:

```
Redirect "/" "http://domain.com/some-user/"
```